# windows batch kill a process

Tags: batch-file, netstat, taskkill

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3808
```

How to kill this process with pid?

my command:

```
for /f "delims=, tokens=5" %%a in ('netstat -ano | findstr 0.0.0.0:8080') do ( taskkill /f /pid %%a )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are close! You're missing that the pipe character `|` has to be escaped in batch using a caret `^` and that the arguments (`delims` and `tokens`) are not separated by a `,`. Actually you can leave delims out completely.

So in total your command would look like this:

```
for /f "tokens=5" %%a in ('netstat -ano ^| findstr 0.0.0.0:8080') do (taskkill /f /pid %%a)
```